# Cannot assign value of type 'IndexPath' to type 'Int'

Tags: swift

I wonder how to declare a variable of type IndexPath. It will also be very helpful if someone can show me how to use inline conditional for this.

```
var indexPath = 0
if  PlaylistController.shared.playlists.count == 1 {
    indexPath = IndexPath(item: sender.tag +1, section: 0)
}
else {
    indexPath = IndexPath(item: sender.tag -1, section: 0)
}
```

Comment: I have this line: ObjectsController.shared.playlists[indexPath.item]

Is it posible to replace [indexPath.item] with something like [$0], all possible values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the line:

```
var indexPath = 0
```

to:

```
let indexPath: IndexPath
```

Or replace the whole thing with:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: sender.tag + (PlaylistController.shared.playlists.count == 1 ? 1 : -1), section: 0)
```

Comment: It is implicitly in your answer, but might be worth to be mentioned explicitly: `indexPath` can be declared as a *constant* if it is initialized exactly once (on each possible code path).

Comment: @MartinR Good point. I chose `let` in the first option of my answer because the OP's remaining code would give `indexPath` a value in the `if/else`. But I probably should have explained why `let` is valid in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
let indexPath : IndexPath = 
    PlaylistController.shared.playlists.count == 1 ?
        IndexPath(item: sender.tag+1, section: 0) :
        IndexPath(item: sender.tag-1, section: 0)
```

Or, clearer I think:

```
let item = PlaylistController.shared.playlists.count == 1 ? sender.tag+1 :sender.tag-1
let indexPath = IndexPath(item:item, section:0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just specify type of your variable as `IndexPath` since this is type which you need to store (you don't want to save number)

```
var indexPath: IndexPath
```

Comment: Well I tried it first, but I got "Expected member name or constructor call after type name". Seems like it works with var indexPath = IndexPath.self

Comment: @twix use colon `:` not equal symbol `=`